# SQL lat longs within lat long bounds

Tags: mysql, sql, location, geometry, latitude-longitude

I am using MySQL 5.5.52. Abbreviations: Lat = Latitude, Long = Longitude, NE = North East, SW = South West.

I have two SQL tables:

First table contains "Areas". Each Area consists of ID, NE Lat, NE Long, SW Lat, SW Long.

Second table contains "Points". Each Point consists of ID, Lat, Long.

I need a SQL statement that given a list of Area IDs will return the Points in those Areas. A Point is defined being in an Area if its Lat-Long lies within the square where the top-right and bottom-left corners are defined by the Area's NE Lat-Long and SW Lat-Long.

*Note: I could change the Areas to be defined as a single Lat-Long with a radius, where Points are found within the 'circles'. But ideally I don't want to do this unless there is a much more efficient SQL statement to solve this way.*

Comment: So something like this: `WHERE (Points.Lat > Areas.SWLat AND Points.LAT < Areas.NWLat) AND (Points.Long > Areas.SWLong AND Points.Long < Areas.NWLong)` ? I think a good question is why they aren't stored as spatial data (or are they)? If you update the post to include your DML it will help a lot.

Comment: The short answer is I've never stored spatial data in a DB before and didn't know the best way. RKRC's answer seems to do the job for me. Is there an advantage of doing it your way (in a where clause rather than a join)?

Comment: For all intents and purposes they are (usually) the same thing. `Between` is inclusive so it's <= and >=. As for Join ON vs WHERE, they are usually the same execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join two tables based on condition that point location falls within area bounds.

```
Select areaTable.*, pointsTable.*
From pointsTable
Join areaTable
On pointTable.lat between areaTable.SWLat and areaTable.NELat
and
pointTable.long between areaTable.SWLong and areaTable.NELong
```

Gives you each area and the corresponding points.

Parameterize further if needed with where clause for specific area.

```
Where areaTable.NELat=@areaNELat
and areaTable.NELong=@areaNELong
and areaTable.SWLat=@areaSWLat
and areaTable.SWLong=@areaSWLong
```

Just substitute @s with the area lat and long values you like.

Comment: That seems to work! However for my where clause I am simply doing `where areaTable.id in (1,2,3...)` It seems to produce the desired result, is this a good idea?

Comment: Be careful! Using a simple `between` statement may fail if the box created by your SW corner and your NE corner straddles the 180th meridian in the Pacific and you're using negative meridian values for half of the planet. For example if West is negative, then you may cover north america and much of the Pacific with corners at 160 and -75 longitude. But then a `between` statement would return wrongly return true for everything with a longitude *outside* of north america.